# Django ValueError sending forms to template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have just added another form to send to my template and I have begun to have this error. It isn't very descriptive so I can't work out what I've done wrong.

The error is 
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

views.py:

```
def new_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewPostForm(request.POST)
        election_form = ElectionSuggestionForm(request.POST, request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = Candidate.objects.get(UserID=request.user, ElectionID=election_form.PostElection)
            post.save()
            return redirect('/feed/')
    else:    
        form = NewPostForm()
        election_form = ElectionSuggestionForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'campaign/new_post.html', {
        "form": form,
        "election_form": election_form,
    })
```

I think the error comes from the last line - the `"election_form"` item in the dictionary - which is confusing since there are only 2 items passed in the dictionary, thus contradicting the error message.

Here is the offending form (The view was working with only `NewPostForm()` so I haven't included this.):

forms.py:

```
def GetAvailableElections(user):
    candidates = Candidate.objects.all().filter(UserID=user)
    choices = []
    for i in candidates:
        choices.append(i.ElectionID.Name)
    return choices

class ElectionSuggestionForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ElectionSuggestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['PostElection'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GetAvailableElections(user))
```

Here is the full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cbuch1800\Coursework\mysite\elections\views.py", line 62, in new_post
    "election_form": election_form,
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1046, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1024, in render_value_in_context
    value = force_text(value)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 76, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 385, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 41, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 101, in as_widget
    attrs = self.build_widget_attrs(attrs, widget)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 257, in build_widget_attrs
    if widget.use_required_attribute(self.initial) and self.field.required and self.form.use_required_attribute:
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 690, in use_required_attribute
    return use_required_attribute and first_choice is not None and self._choice_has_empty_value(first_choice)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 673, in _choice_has_empty_value
    value, _ = choice
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the full traceback, it will show where the `ValueError` is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ElectionSuggestionForm` takes `user` as the first argument.

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
```

Therefore you must pass `user` as the first argument:

```
election_form = ElectionSuggestionForm(request.user, request.POST)
```

You've currently got the arguments the wrong way round.

The `too many values to unpack` error is probably because of your `GetAvailableElections` method. Make sure it returns a list of tuples, e.g. `[('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C')]`. At the moment it's returning a list e.g. `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Comment: I have made this change to the code but the error remains the same. The error is occurring when rendering the page for the first time and not when submitting the form, thus is not within the `if request.method == 'POST': ` statement.

Comment: The problem is in your `GetAvailableElections` method.